# JTable: changing column based on outside input

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable, tablecolumn

I have a custom table class which extends JTable. I want a column to be visible/invisible based on a checkbox. I have an actionlistener on the checkbox that changes the max, min, and preferred width of the column in action.

When the checkbox is NOT selected, then I set the min/max/preferred width to 0. When it is selected, I set the min/max/preferred width to a normal size.

My issue is, when I click to select the checkbox, the table does not change. I do not see the column. However, when I resize the application or any of table columns, the table gets updated and my new column is now visible properly.

I tried calling "table.repaint()", and that did not do anything. My ideal approach now would be to just figure out what gets called during an application/column resize that causes the update, and just call it from my listener.

Comment: post an [mcve] so we can understand what you did

Comment: Rather than changing the *view*, consider making the change at the *Model* - you could do so by creating two TableModel's, one for each type and change the JTable model accordingly

Comment: `when I resize the application or any of table columns, the table gets updated and my new column is now visible properly.` You need to let the LayoutManager know a change has taken place. try calling `revalidate`, but take into consideration the alternative in my comment above

Answer (score 3):

> I have an actionlistener on the checkbox that changes the max, min, and preferred width of the column in action.

Don't play with the column size. The column will still be part of the table and will confuse the user as they tab from column to column since the cursor will disappear on the minimized column.

Instead you want to remove the column from the view of the table. So you need to remove a `TableColumn` from the `TableColumnModel` of the table.

Check out the [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/). This allows you to hide/show columns as required.